# Component is not rendering again React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is simple program of React JS when i update its running render method but not re-rendering Component again

**this is how updating state**

```
this.setState({q_no : this.state.q_no +1 });
```

**Render Method**

```
render(){
        const {loading, q_no, questions} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="container cond7sdagF">
                <h3><i>{this.quizInd.name}</i></h3>
                {!loading && <h6>Loading</h6>}
                {loading && <Question question={questions[q_no]} nextQuestion={this.nextQuestion} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the state?

Comment: You should update your state like this:

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      q_no: prevstate.q_no + 1
    })
can you share your whole class? I don't see any reason for it to not update, maybe you are using a Pure component?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: On a side note aren't you swapping `!loading` and `loading` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a typo or not but it seems that your conditions are backwards:

This

```
        {!loading && <h6>Loading</h6>}
        {loading && <Question question={questions[q_no]} nextQuestion={this.nextQuestion} />}
```

Should be like this

```
            {loading && <h6>Loading</h6>}
            {!loading && <Question question={questions[q_no]} nextQuestion={this.nextQuestion} />}
```

Another thing, when ever your new state is based on the previous state, [its better to use the functional version](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate) of `setState`:

```
this.setState(state => ({q_no : state.q_no +1 }));
```